# export all records to Algolia index with Firestore Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I'm stuck on the syntax for using a Firestore Cloud Function to get all the existing documents and index them in Algolia. I should only really want to do this once, but it would be really great to understand how to do this.

My config at the top of index.js is:

```
    "use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.generateCustomerReportLink = exports.createUser = exports.helloWorld = void 0;

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch')

admin.initializeApp();

const actionCodeSettings = {
    // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for
    // this URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
    url: 'https://www.myurl.com',
    // This must be true for email link sign-in.
    handleCodeInApp: true,
};

const ALGOLIA_ID = functions.config().algolia.app;
const ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY = functions.config().algolia.api_key;
// const ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY = functions.config().algolia.search_key;

const client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);
const ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME = 'Sessions';
const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
```

All the docs I can find either don't use a cloud function or use a cloud function trigger like onWrite like in these examples [cloud function examples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fulltext-search/functions/index.js)

It looks like the syntax

```
exports.indexentry = functions.database.ref('/blog-posts/{blogid}/text').onWrite(
```

only works with the trigger method?

I currently have functions set up and working and my algolia config is set up correctly because I have a cloud function triggered by onCreate that creates a new index in algolia and it works great.

My code for the function I'm trying to write to index all existing docs is like so:

```
const ALGOLIA_ID = functions.config().algolia.app;
const ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY = functions.config().algolia.api_key;
// const ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY = functions.config().algolia.search_key;

const client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);
const ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME = 'Sessions';
const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);


const _collection = admin.firestore().collection('sessions');

exports.sendCollectionToAlgolia = functions._collection.once('value', sessions => {
// Build an array of all records to push to Algolia
const records = [];
sessions.forEach(session => {
  // get the key and data from the snapshot
  const childKey = session.key;
  const childData = session;
  // We set the Algolia objectID as the Firebase .key
  childData.objectID = childKey;
  // Add object for indexing
  records.push({
        sessionDate: childData.sessionDate,
        customer1FirstName: childData.customer1FirstName,
        customer1LastName: childData.customer1LastName
    }); 
});

// Add or update new objects
index
  .saveObjects(records)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Contacts imported into Algolia');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error when importing contact into Algolia', error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

});

But then I get an error on deploy:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined
```

If I use this code for my cloud function, which is based on the code examples here [algolia docs firestore examples](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/sending-and-managing-data/send-and-update-your-data/tutorials/firebase-algolia/#introduction)the function deploys, but when I call test the function url in my browser I get 408 and the request times out.

```
exports.sendCollectionToAlgolia = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    // This array will contain all records to be indexed in Algolia.
    // A record does not need to necessarily contain all properties of the Firestore document,
    // only the relevant ones. 
    const algoliaRecords = [];

    // Retrieve all documents from the COLLECTION collection.
    const querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('Sessions').get();

    querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        const document = doc.data();
        // Essentially, you want your records to contain any information that facilitates search, 
        // display, filtering, or relevance. Otherwise, you can leave it out.
        const record = {
            objectID: doc.id,
            sessionDate: document.sessionDate,
            customer1FirstName: document.customer1FirstName,
            customer1LastName: document.customer1LastName
        };

        algoliaRecords.push(record);
    });
    
    // After all records are created, we save them to 
    index.saveObjects(algoliaRecords, (_error, content) => {
        res.status(200).send("COLLECTION was indexed to Algolia successfully.");
    });
    
})
```

Comment: Can you show the **entire** code of your Cloud Function?

Comment: I have a bunch of config stuff at the top. There are other functions, but they are separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a few things wrong. Most of all the error turned out to be a simple js error where the list being passed to the saveObjects() function was always length 0 so I changed the scope of the list and chained it in the promise with then:

```
const runtimeOpts = {
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '1GB'
  }

// Get all sessions from Firebase
exports.sendCollectionToAlgolia = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

admin.firestore().collection("sessions").get().then((docs) => {

    let _sessions = [];

    docs.forEach((doc) => {

        let session = doc.data();

        const childKey = doc.id;

        if (
            session.customerInfo.customers.customer1.customerFirstName && 
            session.customerInfo.customers.customer1.customerLastName
        ) {
            const childData = {
                indexData: {
                    sessionDate: session.sessionDate,
                    customer1FirstName: session.customerInfo.customers.customer1.customerFirstName,
                    customer1LastName: session.customerInfo.customers.customer1.customerLastName,
                }
            }

            childData.objectID = childKey;
            _sessions.push(childData);
        }
    })
    return _sessions;
}).then((_sessions) => {

    index.saveObjects(_sessions)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Contacts imported into Algolia');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error when importing contact into Algolia', error);
      process.exit(1);
    });
})
```

});

As a side note - logging entire arrays of document fields only works when you have very small docs. Logging the entire output of anything in the cloud functions console is a bad idea!

Answer (score 1):

For:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined
```

You are using the realtime database syntax. For Firestore it would be:

```
exports.indexentry = functions.firestore.document('/blog-posts/{blogid}/text').onWrite(
```

The docs for that are [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

Comment: That will only trigger on an event like onWrite - I need the syntax for a function I can call from a url

Comment: Oh I see, so is it the ```exports.sendCollectionToAlgolia``` function that is returning 408 when you attempt to run it from a url?

Comment: The second version beginning functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => returns 408. The first version, doesn't deploy. I don't think I can do functions.firestore.document('sessions/{sessionID}').once()

Comment: It gives the error TypeError: functions.firestore.document(...).once is not a function

Comment: Are you on a blaze plan for your Firebase project? You may already know this but if you are on the free plan you will not be able to make calls to external resources from cloud functions on the free plan.

Comment: Which may explain the 408. I know I went through a lot of pain when I first started using algolia just because I wasnt on a paid firebase plan and it drove me nutty

Comment: I am on the Blaze plan! Yeah it was quite frustrating doing other stuff til I figured that out

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. At this point if I had your code I would log to the console and figure out where your onRequest function is getting stuck. If you console.log inside the cloud function you can read them in your cloud function logs

Comment: I did find a solution by rigorously debugging my console, but I'm still no wiser as to why the code example in the docs didn't work!